# What's a way around SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry | Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

**Error:**

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '7e88079cec' for key 'unique_email_id'

I'm importing data from an API and storing it into a database.

It works on the first try but doesn't update it. I know why wouldn't a "replace" work? Laravel docs don't seem to have a replaceOrUpdate. Do I have to resort to old SQL queries?

```
$members = Newsletter::getMembers('subscribers');
foreach($members['members'] as $member)
{
  DB::table('newsletter')->where('email', $member['email_address'])->updateOrInsert([
    'email' => $member['email_address'],
    'unique_email_id' => $member['unique_email_id'],
    'web_id' => $member['web_id'],
    'status' => $member['status'],
    'created_at' => $member['timestamp_opt'],
    'updated_at' => $member['last_changed']
  ]);
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#updates. You have to pass two arguments to the `updateOrInsert()` method. The first argument specifies the keys on which to search, and the second contains the data which to fill. So in your case, drop the "where" clause and move those into an array as your first argument. Read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods) on the Eloquent instance instead, like this:

```
foreach($members['members'] as $member)
{
    Newsletter::updateOrCreate(['email' => $member['email_address']], 
        [
           'unique_email_id' => $member['unique_email_id'],
           'web_id' => $member['web_id'],
           'status' => $member['status'],
           'created_at' => $member['timestamp_opt'],
           'updated_at' => $member['last_changed']
    ]);
}
```

So the first param (array) is used as a where clause, if found it will update if not it will create a new record.